# How to pick a random integer out of three integers I chose

Tags: c, random, integer

I am making a trivia game and have questions in functions to get a random question I am trying to pick a random integer that is 0, 1, or 2. Depending on what I get I will then point to a function and run that function. I want to then make it so when I do this again I can make sure I don't get this integer again so as to not run the same question.

This is what I have now

```
  srand(time(NULL));
  int randomnumber;
  randomnumber = rand() % 3;
```

but it is just getting a random integer between 0 and 2 and then not letting me select three direct integers and then take them out of this array if run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a small number of items, replace the selected item with an invalid value.
A switch could be used to process the random items.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main( void) {
    char items[] = "012";
    int each = 0;

    srand ( time ( NULL));

    while ( 1) {
        if ( ! strcmp ( "   ", items)) {
            printf ( "all items used\n");
            break;
        }

        do {//find an item that is not ' '
            each = rand ( ) % 3;
        } while ( items[each] == ' ');

        switch ( items[each]) {
            case '0':
                printf ( "using item 0\n");
                //do other things here as needed
                break;
            case '1':
                printf ( "using item 1\n");
                //do other things here as needed
                break;
            case '2':
                printf ( "using item 2\n");
                //do other things here as needed
                break;
        }

        items[each] = ' ';//set used item to ' '
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you this will really help me.

Answer (score 2):

There are many approaches to go for. One of them will be to create an array of integers, in your case it will be of size three with numbers 0...2 in it. Now shuffle this array. There are many algorithms available to do this. One example will be [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).
Now, just loop through this newly created shuffle array to call the functions. In this case, both your requirements will be taken care of. The **questions will be in random order and you won't be calling the same number again**.

This code sample will help you to get started:

```
void shuffle ( int arr[], int n ) {
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    //this will shuffle the array
    for (int i = n-1; i > 0; i--){
        // Pick a random index from 0 to i-1
        int j = rand() % (i);
        // Swap arr[i] with the element at random index
        swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
    }
}
int main(){
    int arr[] = {0, 1, 2};
    shuffle(arr, 3);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        // call the function with shuffled array
    }
}
```

You need to write the **swap function**.

Comment: I missed "_when I do this again I can make sure I don't get this integer again ..._" in the question, so I deleted my answer and I upvote yours  :-)

Comment: I understand what this is trying to get me to do but don't understand how I'm supposed to put it into code that will work.

Comment: @bobbyjoe. I have added some code to hep you get started.